# Is possible share photo from my app without publish_actions on facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, image, share, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I did not obtain publish_actions yet. Is possible upload image to facebook from my android application without publish_action permission?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if the user has the Facebook app installed.

You can do it via the FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder/).

There's also an example demonstrating this in the Hello Facebook sample app.

Comment: Thanks. Is possible to set description for uploaded image?

Comment: No, Platform Policies does not allow your app to prefill the description, they need to type it in themselves. Since the Facebook app's composer allows them to type in a message, there's no ability to specify one here.

Comment: With facebook sdk and with native app can do this? I can not search class to allow set description.